# Bounds on tail of distribution by sum of tails

Tags: probability

[image]

From what I can see, the tail of the convolution is greater than the stuff approximated by the sum of tails. should this not imply the liminf is greater or equal to one?

Comment: The proof--of which only the beginning is shown--looks like it will supply a rigorous answer to this question.  It is intended to help you understand what the numerator and denominator represent.  Its technique sheds light on just exactly *why* the limit infimum cannot exceed unity.

Comment: @whuber I have shown the full proof. See here for yourself: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iqkbCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=bounds+on+aggregate+tail+distribution&source=bl&ots=48uSAgb24F&sig=cDIq9DQFj-S2aGZwkXDzUpgP05w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-3aPNraXLAhWGQhQKHb9SD_oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=bounds%20on%20aggregate%20tail%20distribution&f=false

Comment: I see--there's nothing left to show.  You should therefore have little trouble working through it.

Comment: @whuber well, I think the proof shows the liminf ratio is actually greater equal to 1, asymptotically, rather than less equal to 1, as claimed. For a (one-sided) normal, doesn't the sum of normal has a tail which behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\exp(-x^2/2n)$ comparing to $n\exp(-x^2/2)$ for the sum of normals. The former in fact decay slower than the latter?

Comment: (+1) I think you're right.  (I need to slow down and read things more carefully!)  One should feel uneasy about the "$\sim$" in the last line, because  it's not rigorous, but I think that gap is easily patched up.

Comment: @whuber I feel more uneasy about the fact, it is $\geq$ rather than $\leq$ in equation, even if we are willing to accept the tilde! My example is not quite right because it is tails, rather than density, but using Mill's ratio, I am only out by a factor of $1/x$, which should not effect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture shows the idea.

[image: Figure]

It depicts the situation with two random variables, plotting $Z_1$ on the horizontal axis and $Z_2$ on the vertical axis.  Region IV is the set where $Z_1 \gt z$ and $Z_2 \le z$.  Provided we pick $z$ large enough, we can guarantee most of the probability of $Z_1$ is in the interval $[0,z]$ and most of the probability of $Z_2$ is in this interval, too.  These are the quantities $F_1(z)$ and $F_2(z)$.  Both lie within an arbitrary narrow range $[1-\epsilon]$. The complementary probabilities are $\bar F_i(z) = 1 - F_i(z)$.

Because $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent, the probability of any rectangle in this picture is the product of the marginal probabilities.  Specifically, the chance that $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is in region $IV$ is

$$\Pr(IV) = \bar {F}_1(z) F_2(z) \ge \bar {F}_1(z) (1-\epsilon ).$$

The same argument, with $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ switched, establishes that the chance of region $II$ is

$$\Pr(II) = \bar{F}_2(z) F_1(z)\ge \bar {F}_2(z) (1-\epsilon ).$$

Now the event $Z_1 + Z_2 \gt z$ consists of regions $I, II, III,$ and $IV$.  The chance that $Z_1+Z_2$ exceeds $z$ obviously equals the sum of the chances of each of the regions (provided we are careful to define their boundaries so they have no overlap).  Consequently

$$\eqalign{
\overline{(F_1 \star F_2)}(z) &= \Pr(Z_1 + Z_2 \gt z) \\
&= \Pr(I)+\Pr(II)+\Pr(III)+\Pr(IV) \\
&\ge \Pr(II) + \Pr(IV) \\
&\ge (1-\epsilon )(\bar{F}_1(z) + \bar{F}_2(z)).
}$$

If $\bar{F}_1(z) + \bar{F}_2(z)=0$ there's nothing to show.  Otherwise, dividing yields

$$\frac{\overline{(F_1 \star F_2)}(z)}{\bar{F}_1(z) + \bar{F}_2(z)} \ge 1-\epsilon $$

for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ provided only that $z$ is chosen sufficiently large (depending on how small $\epsilon $ is).

By definition, this guarantees that the limit infimum of the fraction can be no less than $1-\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$.  But that is equivalent to saying the limit infimum is at least $1$.

The same idea applies directly to more than two random variables (but not necessarily to an infinite number).  The general result also follows, almost immediately, by induction.

Comment: So the result on the book is wrong? (As verified by my normal distribution example?)

Comment: If the correct result is used later on, I would say these are just typographical errors.  If the incorrect result is invoked, though, then there could be a problem and you might be justified in saying it is wrong.